# PowerPC disassembler output different from opcodes

Tags: cpu-architecture, disassembly, powerpc, opcode

Why are the opcodes for powerpc different from what the disassembler outputs?

[Diassambler Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2DTl.png)

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000100000b0 <main>:
    100000b0:   38 22 ff f8      addi   r1,r2,-8
    100000b4:   48 00 00 09      bl     100000bc <_main>
    100000b8:   48 00 00 58      b      10000110 <exit>
```

For instance, for the instruction, "b" the first 6 bits contain the hex value 48. However, on the opcode table, it says that the opcode is 18. Why is this? Am I interpreting the opcodes incorrectly?

Comment: posting external links as the primary source of your question doesnt work here as those links can go away.  post relevant portions of the source and the disassembly on SO in the question.

Comment: @dwelch It wouldn't let me embed the source code for some rason

Comment: you cant cut and paste?  that is effectively just typing...

Comment: @dwelch oh sorry thanks

Comment: 48h does not fit within 6 bits, so that must be a byte value.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError but what about the opcode why doesn't it show up in the disassembler output?

Comment: It does, if a bit indirectly. If you shift the 48h value two bits to the right to isolate the upper 6 bits, you get 12h, which is 18 in decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

18 is in decimal and is bits 0..5 of the top byte 0..7.  So you need to shift it up 2 and convert to hex.  Then you get 0x48. ie.

```
% printf %x $((18 << 2))
48 
%
```